# Finding a dynamically generated button as a descendant of a div

Tags: jquery

I need to find a button inside a div (and do a function on click), I know how to do it in a regular way:

```
$(".some_div").find(".button").click(function () {
  //do something
)};
```

The problem is I have to use the `.on` function because the content is loaded with AJAX, so I am using this:

```
$(document).on('click', '.button', function(event){ 
  //do something
)};
```

I need a combination of those two. I tried this:

```
$(document).on('click', '.some_div' '.button', function(event){ 
  //do something
)};
```

Did not work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [descendant selector, $(“ancestor descendant”)](http://api.jquery.com/descendant-selector/) to get the `.button` within descendants of `.some_div`

```
$(document).on('click', '.some_div .button', function(event){ 
    //do something
)};
```

or if you think the element .some_div is present at the time of bind click event with on then you can use .some_div in place of document.

```
$('.some_div').on('click', '.button', function(event){ 
    //do something
)};
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$(document).on('click', '.some_div .button', function(event){ 
//do something
 )};
```

or

```
$(document).on('click', '.some_div > .button', function(event){ 
//do something
 )};
```